# Is it possible to assign a message to a variable?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I'm studying different kinds of programming languages to see how they differ and their advantages/disadvantages.

I'm currently particularly interested in languages that use messages for method calls; and I was wondering if it's possible to somehow assign a message to a variable in Squeak/Pharo/Smalltalk/etc.

So let's say both class `A` and `B` have the message `foo:`; how can I then do something like this:

```
|msg| 
msg := foo: 12.
a msg.
b msg.
```

Where `a` and `b` are instances of `A` and `B` respectively

Comment: Just to clarify: you're not considering blocks for this? That'd be the first way I'd think of to "transfer" a message call.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I don't really code smalltalk, I'm asking the question from a more educational point of view; but please submit the block idea as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pharo has `Message` class. So you can create it as

```
Message selector: #foo: argument: 12
```

But currently `Message` is not used for execution purposes.

What you are looking for are `perform:` messages.

So you can do what you need like this:

```
| selector arg | 
selector := #foo:.
arg := 12.
a perform: selector with: arg.
b perform: selector with: arg

"for messages of other `shape`"
a perform: selector.
a perform: selector with: arg with: arg. "up to 3 args"
a perform: selector withArguments: { arg . arg }
```

---

#### As for fancy syntax

```
msg := foo: 12.
```

does not make any sense according to Smalltalk. But what you can do is to define a class like `GenericMessage` with 2 instance variables: `selector` and `arguments`. Then you redefine `doesNotUnderstand:` on the class side like this:

```
GenericMessage class >> doesNotUnderstand: aMessage

    ^ self new
        selector: aMessage selector;
        arguments: aMessage arguments;
        yourself
```

Then you also define a method for `Object`:

```
Object>>#performMessage: aGenericMessage

    ^ self
        perform: aGenericMessage selector
        withArguments: aGenericMessage arguments
```

Then your code will look like this:

```
|msg| 
msg := GenericMessage foo: 12.
a performMessage: msg.
b performMessage: msg.
```

Comment: would this also work if the message was of the shape `foo: 12 withBar: 14`? i.e. having more than one argument? Or is that just two messages in Smalltalk instead of one like in Obj-C

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I've added more examples

Comment: @ElectricCoffee also added a reasoning about syntax if it is interesting for you

Comment: I have to design a new programming language for this semester at the universtiy, so added reasoning is much appreciated :)

Comment: Designing a new language that is better than smalltalk is going to be a tough challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether you want just to send a message by it's name or store functionality for later use, you have different options. In the latter case you can use *blocks* which are Smalltalk's version of closures. You define a block as:

```
block = [ :arg | arg foo: 12 ]
```

this means that whenever you evaluate an arg with the block `foo: 12` will be sent to the arg.

Your code will look like this then:

```
|block| 
block := [ :arg | arg foo: 12 ].
block value: a.
block value: b
```

*P.S. I bet you have the same thing in Objective-C and they are also called blocks*

Comment: yeah but aren't blocks just lambda experssions? i.e. anonymous functions

Comment: I think in Smalltalk: blocks are closures, not lambdas.

Comment: @NicoPaez, yes sorry they are closures. And thank to you now I know the difference